# Using consistent phone number as ID

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app where my user's phone number is the ID. I am querying the user's contacts to use them as his friends. I am verifying the user phone number that he is entering and save him in the DB.

The problem is that some contacts may be displayed differently in different phones. Some can begin with the country code, where `+` as the first digit, and many other variations...

How can I find a consistent format for registering the clients so the phone number will be unique and consistent for all of my players?

Comment: What happens when two players have the same phone number? Three?

Comment: Is it possible to happen when I am using the country code?

Answer (score 2):

What happens if a player gets a new phone number? Do they lose all their points?

I'd suggest it's a bad idea to use the phone number as a primary key / account identifier, especially if that's the only way they can access their account. Once their device phone number changes and is no longer in their control, users will suddenly have no access to their account and no obvious way to recover it. Nor would there be any good way to authenticate to a customer support representative that the person asking for support is the real owner of the account in question (they don't have that phone number any more).

So if you aren't going to use the phone number as a piece of identifying data, the formatting doesn't end up being that important after all. And as was mentioned, what if someone has more than one phone number? Which one is the PK? What if someone loses their phone number for not paying their bill, it is reallocated to someone else, who happens to be a game player as well. Imagine what happens if they add points and winnings to the account. Who owns it then?

If you are going to keep phone numbers, by all means save accurate ones, but do so with UI that first understands what country a user is specifying a number for, then make sure the number that is entered has the correct number of digits, then validate the phone number is correct by calling it with an audio code or sending an SMS to the phone if it is a mobile for them to enter back into the website.

Comment: Using user phone number as a username is not inherently a bad idea, and the headache would be primarily on the users who might have to change usernames upon switching phone numbers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'd only disagree because when a user's phone number changes (and a lot of people do use prepay/burner numbers), all of the related records that use the PK will also have to change. If a user gets a new *account* after getting a new phone number, their match and point history is lost as well.

Comment: I believe that working with phone number as the ID is a better UX, the user doesn't have to manage password and friends list. I can add an option for email verification for restoring user's data in case of changing phone number.